# Porting V1 Legacy Code with V2 Viewer3D.js?

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge

I am currently using the following project for Forge IoT data visualization:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app

However, it seems to be using the lmvUrl in SiteConfig to "https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest" for Viewer3D which is now legacy code and no longer support.

Is it possible to port the V2 version of Viewer3D from the following guide to supplement this?
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/starting-html/

I can change the lmvUrl to "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js" or a different version to get retrieve the js file, but due to v1 vs v2, it is obviously not compatible.  I wanted to know if it was possible for any workarounds, or would this project needs to be rebuilt?

Answer (score 0):

We've reworked the original sample application into a new one that is simpler and easier to reuse: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo. Please consider using this source code instead.

Btw. the https://autodeskviewer.com has recently been shut down as it is not an official endpoint for viewer resources.